# Error in UseMethod("group_vars") : no applicable method for 'group_vars' applied to an object of class "character" > - PROBLEM

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

Tried to run the following code to plot a pie chart using ggplot. But its giving this error constantly.

```
ggplot(Q6.1, aes(x="", y= count(market_segment), fill = market_segment)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1)
```

The data name is Q6.1 and it has three columns - Percentage, count(market_segment) and market_segment
and i want to plot a pie chart using Percentage and market_segment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try putting back ticks around `count(market_segment)`, or even better, stick to using legal R names so you don't need to do this.

Comment: ARPAN, the use of backticks (e.g., `y=\`count(markey_segment)\``) tells R to parse that as a whole symbol/variable-name, and not try to parse and evaluate that as a call to the `count` function (found in `dplyr` and other packages) on a variable named `market_segment`.